# Is there an inexpensive method of applying effects to a player based on an item in their inventory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm running a server for a group of friends with a significant number of custom items which give an effect when in the player's inventory (NOT just when held, which minecraft supports natively). Unfortunately, the command block `/execute` processes for these commands are quite expensive, even with optimizations like Lithium.
This is one example of a command I'm currently using, ran in a repeating command block targeting an item with a custom texture:
`/execute if @a[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:raw_gold",display:{Name:'{"Cursed Ruby"}',Lore:['{"text":"When In Inventory:","color":"gray"},{"text":"  Blindness","color":"red"}']}}]}] at @a[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:raw_gold",display:{Name:'{"Cursed Ruby"}',Lore:['{"text":"When In Inventory:","color":"gray"},{"text":"  Blindness","color":"red"}']}}]}] run effect give @p minecraft:blindness 5 1 true`

Selector is below:

```
@a[
 nbt={
  Inventory:[{
   id:"minecraft:raw_gold",
   display:{
    Name:'{"Cursed Ruby"}',
    Lore:['
     {"text":"When In Inventory:","color":"gray"},
     {"text":"  Blindness","color":"red"}
    ']
   }
  }]
 }
]
```

With around 20 similar items in numerous quantities across multiple player inventories, this gets expensive fast. You might notice that I've attempted using an `if` keyword to reduce the impact of the command; it seems to have helped a little bit, but this is still taking roughly 40% of my server's resources.

Is there a way to minimize the performance impact of inventory-based checks, similar to how Minecraft's native `When In Hand` applies it? I can use mods if necessary, but a vanilla solution is preferred.

Comment: Haven't read it all yet, but try `inventory_changed` advancement trigger. Also, general performance stuff: https://github.com/Neylz/opti-mcfunction

Answer (score -1):

There is a plugin named ItemEdit and there is an addon for it named [ItemTag](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/itemtag-1-8-x-1-20-x.89634/). With that plugin you can make that work.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: you mean how to do the commands  for it or just the anwser

Comment: You seem to be pointing in the right direction (I'm not very familiar with Minecraft), but don't really seem to address the specific issue the OP is having, or explain *how* this will help minimize performance.

Comment: what do you mean with that